# Foundation - Removing left and right borders of input box

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've started using Foundation and have a qiestion about best using the framework.

I can see the `$input-border` in my settings.scss file. I want to remove the left and right borders only. I'm trying $input-border-left however I see from the docs thats not supported.

So i know how to do this otherwise in CSS - e.g. i have a custom file and set `border-left: 0px !important`. However when trying this it doesnt work:

```
.input {
  border-left: 0px !important;
}
```

However could someone explain how this is done. Do i need to use mixins?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to target the element - not the class.. `input {
  border-left: 0px !important;
}`

Comment: lmao! Can't believe i didnt see that!
Thanks